# Unauth 401 error when access in-memory h2 console

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa, h2

I am trying to access h2 console and getting 401 error

Running with Spring Boot `v2.7.8`, Spring `v5.3.25` with `Java 17`

```
com.h2database:h2:2.1.214
```

application.yaml

```
server:
  port: 8605

logging:
  level:
    root: debug

spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:myDB
    username: sa
    password:
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
      path: /h2-console
```

SecurityConfig class

```
import static org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.PathRequest.toH2Console;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnProperty;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration

public class H2SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
//            .antMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll();
            .antMatchers(String.valueOf(toH2Console())).permitAll()
        http.csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/h2-console/**");
        http.csrf().ignoringAntMatchers(String.valueOf(toH2Console()));
        http.headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin();
    }
}
```

I receive below error when hit `http://localhost:8605/h2-console`
[image: page access error]
Console Error:

```
Host: localhost:8605
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="111", "Not(A:Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="111"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-AU,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Cookie: entity=; AMCV_67A216D751E567B20A490D4C%40AdobeOrg=-1712354808%7CMCMID%7C46259969725702002272908520088254151094%7CMCAID%7CNONE%7CMCOPTOUT-1674544319s%7CNONE%7CMCAAMLH-1675141919%7C8%7CMCAAMB-1675141919%7Cj8Odv6LonN4r3an7LhD3WZrU1bUpAkFkkiY1ncBR96t2PTI%7CvVersion%7C4.3.0; JSESSIONID=03DBF33D35F05DAAB61535EAB8DE998F

]
 http-nio-8605-exec-1 | sourcesys=my-app | X-B3-TraceId= | X-B3-SpanId= | X-Span-Export= | X-B3-ParentSpanId= | org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters | Set query string encoding to UTF-8
 http-nio-8605-exec-1 | sourcesys=my-app | X-B3-TraceId= | X-B3-SpanId= | X-Span-Export= | X-B3-ParentSpanId= | org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Rfc6265CookieProcessor | Cookies: Parsing b[]: entity=; AMCV_67A216D751E567B20A490D4C%40AdobeOrg=-1712354808%7CMCMID%7C46259969725702002272908520088254151094%7CMCAID%7CNONE%7CMCOPTOUT-1674544319s%7CNONE%7CMCAAMLH-1675141919%7C8%7CMCAAMB-1675141919%7Cj8Odv6LonN4r3an7LhD3WZrU1bUpAkFkkiY1ncBR96t2PTI%7CvVersion%7C4.3.0; JSESSIONID=03DBF33D35F05DAAB61535EAB8DE998F
 http-nio-8605-exec-1 | sourcesys=my-app | X-B3-TraceId= | X-B3-SpanId= | X-Span-Export= | X-B3-ParentSpanId= | org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter |  Requested cookie session id is 03DBF33D35F05DAAB61535EAB8DE998F
 http-nio-8605-exec-1 | sourcesys=my-app | X-B3-TraceId= | X-B3-SpanId= | X-Span-Export= | X-B3-ParentSpanId= | unknown.jul.logger | X-B3-TraceId was null
 http-nio-8605-exec-1 | sourcesys=my-app | X-B3-TraceId= | X-B3-SpanId= | X-Span-Export= | X-B3-ParentSpanId= | org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.tomcat.TraceValve | Created a server receive span [RealSpan(174fb65ea1d069e4/174fb65ea1d069e4)]
 http-nio-8605-exec-1 | sourcesys=my-app | X-B3-TraceId=174fb65ea1d069e4 | X-B3-SpanId=174fb65ea1d069e4 | X-Span-Export=true | X-B3-ParentSpanId= | org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase | Security checking request GET /h2-console
 http-nio-8605-exec-1 | sourcesys=my-app | X-B3-TraceId=174fb65ea1d069e4 | X-B3-SpanId=174fb65ea1d069e4 | X-Span-Export=true | X-B3-ParentSpanId= | org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase |   No applicable constraints defined
 http-nio-8605-exec-1 | sourcesys=my-app | X-B3-TraceId=174fb65ea1d069e4 | X-B3-SpanId=174fb65ea1d069e4 | X-Span-Export=true | X-B3-ParentSpanId= | org.apache.catalina.authenticator.jaspic.AuthConfigFactoryImpl | Loading persistent provider registrations from [C:\Users\smph\AppData\Local\Temp\1\tomcat.8605.5585913941152052122\conf\jaspic-providers.xml]
 http-nio-8605-exec-1 | sourcesys=my-app | X-B3-TraceId=174fb65ea1d069e4 | X-B3-SpanId=174fb65ea1d069e4 | X-Span-Export=true | X-B3-ParentSpanId= | org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase | Not subject to any constraint
 http-nio-8605-exec-1 | sourcesys=my-app | X-B3-TraceId=174fb65ea1d069e4 | X-B3-SpanId=174fb65ea1d069e4 | X-Span-Export=true | X-B3-ParentSpanId= | com.my.common.filter.OAuth2AuthenticationDetailsFilter | Constructing OAuth2 authentication details with pre-authenticated authentication token for request to api=/h2-console
 http-nio-8605-exec-1 | sourcesys=my-app | X-B3-TraceId= | X-B3-SpanId= | X-Span-Export= | X-B3-ParentSpanId= | org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.tomcat.TraceValve | Handled send of span [RealSpan(174fb65ea1d069e4/174fb65ea1d069e4)]
 http-nio-8605-exec-1 | sourcesys=my-app | X-B3-TraceId= | X-B3-SpanId= | X-Span-Export= | X-B3-ParentSpanId= | org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer | Before fill(): parsingHeader: [true], parsingRequestLine: [true], parsingRequestLinePhase: [0], parsingRequestLineStart: [0], byteBuffer.position(): [0], byteBuffer.limit(): [0], end: [1035]
 http-nio-8605-exec-1 | sourcesys=my-app | X-B3-TraceId= | X-B3-SpanId= | X-Span-Export= | X-B3-ParentSpanId= | org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase | Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@47937c59:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@7c4d211a:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:8605 remote=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:9736]], Read from buffer: [0]
 http-nio-8605-exec-1 | sourcesys=my-app | X-B3-TraceId= | X-B3-SpanId= | X-Span-Export= | X-B3-ParentSpanId= | org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint | Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@47937c59:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@7c4d211a:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:8605 remote=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:9736]], Read direct from socket: [0]
 http-nio-8605-exec-1 | sourcesys=my-app | X-B3-TraceId= | X-B3-SpanId= | X-Span-Export= | X-B3-ParentSpanId= | org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer | Received []
 http-nio-8605-exec-1 | sourcesys=my-app | X-B3-TraceId= | X-B3-SpanId= | X-Span-Export= | X-B3-ParentSpanId= | org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor | Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@47937c59:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@7c4d211a:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:8605 remote=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:9736]], Status in: [OPEN_READ], State out: [OPEN]
 http-nio-8605-exec-1 | sourcesys=my-app | X-B3-TraceId= | X-B3-SpanId= | X-Span-Export= | X-B3-ParentSpanId= | org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint | Registered read interest for [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@47937c59:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@7c4d211a:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:8605 remote=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:9736]]
 myAPIHikariCP housekeeper | sourcesys=my-app | X-B3-TraceId= | X-B3-SpanId= | X-Span-Export= | X-B3-ParentSpanId= | com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool | myAPIHikariCP - Before cleanup stats (total=1, active=0, idle=1, waiting=0)
 myAPIHikariCP housekeeper | sourcesys=my-app | X-B3-TraceId= | X-B3-SpanId= | X-Span-Export= | X-B3-ParentSpanId= | com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool | myAPIHikariCP - After cleanup  stats (total=1, active=0, idle=1, waiting=0)
 myAPIHikariCP housekeeper | sourcesys=my-app | X-B3-TraceId= | X-B3-SpanId= | X-Span-Export= | X-B3-ParentSpanId= | com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool | myAPIHikariCP - Fill pool skipped, pool is at sufficient level.
 myAPIHikariCP housekeeper | sourcesys=my-app | X-B3-TraceId= | X-B3-SpanId= | X-Span-Export= | X-B3-ParentSpanId= | com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool | myAPIHikariCP - Before cleanup stats (total=1, active=0, idle=1, waiting=0)
 myAPIHikariCP housekeeper | sourcesys=my-app | X-B3-TraceId= | X-B3-SpanId= | X-Span-Export= | X-B3-ParentSpanId= | com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool | myAPIHikariCP - After cleanup  stats (total=1, active=0, idle=1, waiting=0)
 myAPIHikariCP housekeeper | sourcesys=my-app | X-B3-TraceId= | X-B3-SpanId= | X-Span-Export= | X-B3-ParentSpanId= | com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool | myAPIHikariCP - Fill pool skipped, pool is at sufficient level.
 Catalina-utility-2 | sourcesys=my-app | X-B3-TraceId= | X-B3-SpanId= | X-Span-Export= | X-B3-ParentSpanId= | org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase | Start expire sessions StandardManager at 1680133823081 sessioncount 0
 Catalina-utility-2 | sourcesys=my-app | X-B3-TraceId= | X-B3-SpanId= | X-Span-Export= | X-B3-ParentSpanId= | org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase | End expire sessions StandardManager processingTime 0 expired sessions: 0
 http-nio-8605-exec-2 | sourcesys=my-app | X-B3-TraceId= | X-B3-SpanId= | X-Span-Export= | X-B3-ParentSpanId= | org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.LimitLatch | Counting down[http-nio-8605-exec-2] latch=2
 http-nio-8605-exec-2 | sourcesys=my-app | X-B3-TraceId= | X-B3-SpanId= | X-Span-Export= | X-B3-ParentSpanId= | org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint | Calling [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint@3f9f4266].closeSocket([org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@47937c59:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@7c4d211a:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:8605 remote=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:9736]])
 http-nio-8605-exec-3 | sourcesys=my-app | X-B3-TraceId= | X-B3-SpanId= | X-Span-Export= | X-B3-ParentSpanId= | org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.LimitLatch | Counting down[http-nio-8605-exec-3] latch=1
 http-nio-8605-exec-3 | sourcesys=my-app | X-B3-TraceId= | X-B3-SpanId= | X-Span-Export= | X-B3-ParentSpanId= | org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint | Calling [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint@3f9f4266].closeSocket([org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@26260bf8:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@22198be4:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:8605 remote=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:9737]])
 myAPIHikariCP housekeeper | sourcesys=my-app | X-B3-TraceId= | X-B3-SpanId= | X-Span-Export= | X-B3-ParentSpanId= | com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool | myAPIHikariCP - Before cleanup stats (total=1, active=0, idle=1, waiting=0)
 myAPIHikariCP housekeeper | sourcesys=my-app | X-B3-TraceId= | X-B3-SpanId= | X-Span-Export= | X-B3-ParentSpanId= | com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool | myAPIHikariCP - After cleanup  stats (total=1, active=0, idle=1, waiting=0)
 myAPIHikariCP housekeeper | sourcesys=my-app | X-B3-TraceId= | X-B3-SpanId= | X-Span-Export= | X-B3-ParentSpanId= | com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool | myAPIHikariCP - Fill pool skipped, pool is at sufficient level.
 myAPIHikariCP housekeeper | sourcesys=my-app | X-B3-TraceId= | X-B3-SpanId= | X-Span-Export= | X-B3-ParentSpanId= | com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool | myAPIHikariCP - Before cleanup stats (total=1, active=0, idle=1, waiting=0)
 myAPIHikariCP housekeeper | sourcesys=my-app | X-B3-TraceId= | X-B3-SpanId= | X-Span-Export= | X-B3-ParentSpanId= | com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool | myAPIHikariCP - After cleanup  stats (total=1, active=0, idle=1, waiting=0)
 myAPIHikariCP housekeeper | sourcesys=my-app | X-B3-TraceId= | X-B3-SpanId= | X-Span-Export= | X-B3-ParentSpanId= | com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool | myAPIHikariCP - Fill pool skipped, pool is at sufficient level.
 Catalina-utility-2 | sourcesys=my-app | X-B3-TraceId= | X-B3-SpanId= | X-Span-Export= | X-B3-ParentSpanId= | org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase | Start expire sessions StandardManager at 1680133883102 sessioncount 0
 Catalina-utility-2 | sourcesys=my-app | X-B3-TraceId= | X-B3-SpanId= | X-Span-Export= | X-B3-ParentSpanId= | org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase | End expire sessions StandardManager processingTime 0 expired sessions: 0
 myAPIHikariCP housekeeper | sourcesys=my-app | X-B3-TraceId= | X-B3-SpanId= | X-Span-Export= | X-B3-ParentSpanId= | com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool | myAPIHikariCP - Before cleanup stats (total=1, active=0, idle=1, waiting=0)
 myAPIHikariCP housekeeper | sourcesys=my-app | X-B3-TraceId= | X-B3-SpanId= | X-Span-Export= | X-B3-ParentSpanId= | com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool | myAPIHikariCP - After cleanup  stats (total=1, active=0, idle=1, waiting=0)
 myAPIHikariCP housekeeper | sourcesys=my-app | X-B3-TraceId= | X-B3-SpanId= | X-Span-Export= | X-B3-ParentSpanId= | com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool | myAPIHikariCP - Fill pool skipped, pool is at sufficient level.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a solution I had to exclude `OAuth2AuthenticationDetailsFilterAutoConfiguration` in application properties.

```
spring:
  autoconfigure:
    exclude:
      - com.my.autoconfigure.filter.OAuth2AuthenticationDetailsFilterAutoConfiguration
```

Other option would be exclude that url in below override in `OncePerRequestFilter` abstarct class in spring-web dep. In this case ypu don't have to define separate class like `H2SecurityConfiguration`

```
@Override
protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String path = request.getRequestURI();
    return path.startsWith("/h2-console");
}
```